# Is it possible to solve a deductive reasoning test question using python?

Tags: python, equation, simultaneous

Given a verbal question in a deductive reasoning style, is it possible to solve in python?

If the potential variables are never assigned a real world/solid value rather a distance from each other, can it be done? Meaning there is no fixed starting point (i.e. x = 1).

I have tried assigning all variables a `0` to start with and then building from there, but I think this isn't right.

I have an example question here to try, and I have included what I kind of imagine the code to look like. I know its not written in the perfect PEP8 style so please don't criticize that...It is more of a possible example of how I have tried solving the question.

```
"""Denise arrived at the party 1 hour later than Kylie and 30 minutes before James.
Melissa arrived at the party 30 minutes earlier than Denise and 45 minutes earlier than Sarah.

Is the statement below True?

When James arrived, he found both Melissa and Denise enjoying the party and learned that Sarah
arrived at the party 30 minutes prior to him."""

def deductive_reasoning():
    kylie = 0
    james = 0
    denise = 0
    sarah = 0

    melissa = [denise - 30, sarah - 45]
    denise = [kylie + 60, james - 30]
    if (james > melissa[0] and melissa[1]) and (james > denise[0] and denise[1]) and (sarah == james - 30):
        print("That is true")
    else:
        print("That is not true")

deductive_reasoning()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
def deductive_reasoning():
    # "Denise arrived at the party 1 hour later than Kylie"
    # Some time point needs to be pinned, so we'll arbitrarily pin Kylie
    kylie = 0

    # and set Denise relative to Kylie
    denise = 60

    # "and 30 minutes before James"
    james = denise + 30

    # "Melissa arrived as the party 30 minutes earlier that Danise"
    melissa = denise - 30

    # "and 45 minutes earlier than Sarah"
    sarah = melissa + 45
    
    # Query: Did James arrive at a time after both Melissa and Denise
    #        and 30 minutes after Sarah?
    return james > melissa and james > denise and james - sarah == 30
```

It's possible to write a function which encodes that specific logic puzzle. But did the software solve the puzzle or did the programmer solve it in the process of converting the puzzle to code? Personally, I'd say it was the programmer.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, in fact it would take longer to write this code out than to just figure it out on paper. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given above is totally true, but to automate all of this, you need to involve NLP, following is the way, first of all apply NER to text, to get all the names in text, then find all the given times in different format(1:30, 30) etc, and read the words following the time, (minutes, hour), at last, we need the words following minutes/hour which would tell us whether its ahead of basetime (0) or behind it. Words which will describe this would be ('ahead','later','earlier'), we can get list of synonyms of these words and decide whether it was before or after basetime, this way, we can send all the arguments to the function made by @Ouroborus and this can be automated to a certain level.

Comment: That would be very impressive if implemented, but seems like something much easier said than done.  Also, assuming NLP is 'Natural Language Processing', wouldn't that encounter reliability issues, for example if a word problem used a nonstandard sentence structure?  I don't know that this kind of machine learning technique can ever be made 100% accurate, because of the unpredictability inherent in the human-generated input (i.e. the word problems being solved).  Like how Google Translate is a great resource in general but sometimes fails spectacularly :D

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I think the best we have at the moment for this sort of problem is GPT-3 which is able to solve math word problems (as opposed to logic word problems) at close to a 9-12 year old level. See [Solving Math Word Problems](https://openai.com/blog/grade-school-math/).